# PHP + jQuery gallery

Tags: php, jquery, image, gallery

I have this code:

```
<img src="'. $random_pics[$i] .'" width="'.$thumb_width.'" alt="" name="?album='. urlencode($albums[$i]) .'" class="alb" />

<div id="pictures"></div>
<script>
$('.alb').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('name');
    $("#pictures").load('display.php'+href)
});
</script>
```

Then I have a `display.php` file, where I use `$_GET['album']` to get the album name and display the photos from that album. 
How it should work: when I click the image, the `pictures` div should load the `display.php?album=somealbum`, but for some reason it does not... My files are bigger, but I think the problem is here.

Comment: where is `?album=` for `href`?

Comment: `name="?album='. urlencode($albums[$i]) .'"`

Comment: Have you looked at your browser developer tools (console.log, firebug, etc) to make sure your function is firing, and that the url is correct? What you posted should work, as demonstrated in this simple jsFiddle, where I only changed `.load` to `.html` - http://jsfiddle.net/FkAm9/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed the php tags around each of those embedded php codes. Or perhaps there should be more to the snippet you provided?

```
<img src="<?php echo $random_pics[$i]; ?>"
     width="<?php echo $thumb_width; ?>"
     alt=""
     name="?album=<?php echo urlencode($albums[$i]); ?>"
     class="alb" />
```